# Quicklists for Unity Launcher's Home Folder icon not working when Nautilus is closed

Tags: nautilus, launcher, quicklists

If **Nautilus** File Manager is closed and I right-click on its **Home Folder** icon on Unity Launcher, only the tab "Open in a new window" appears. **Quicklists**(with all my Bookmarks) of the Home Folder icon works only when Nautilus is already open.

I really don't understand what might have happened...

How to restore it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Quicklists), there are two type of quicklists: static and dynamic. Bookmarks quicklist is a dynamic quicklist. So, it will be available only if your `nautilus` is running.

`nautilus` is always running in background unless you or some process killed it.

If you disabled `nautilus` to manage your desktop (for example you hid desktop icons) to restore quicklists you can:

1. Open a folder. From now on nautilus will be running even if you close all Nautilus windows, so quicklists will be displayed.
2. Just add `nautilus -n` to a start-up script like `.xsessionrc` in your home folder (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/264378/54949)). Or go to Startup Applications, click "Add" and insert the command `nautilus -n`. This way you can have nautilus autostarting in the
   background even if hide-desktop-icons feature is in use.

Comment: ok, I found the solution: I have my desktop icons hidden (this means nautilus was not able to manage my desktop) so nautilus wasn't running in background. To restore the quicklist also when nautilus windows are closed, I just disabled this feature. Thanks, you brought me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing IgniteE's solution:

There is no need to re-enable show-desktop-icons feature. Instead, just add `nautilus -n` to a start-up script like `.xsessionrc` in your homefolder. This way you can have nautilus autostarting in the background even if hide-desktop-icons feature is in use.